# In Sequelize How to order by `column_a - column_b`?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

In my project I am using node.js v10, sequelize 5.8.9 and Postgres 11.

In database there is a `Task` table and a few child tables. I have done the sequelize model definition, and the create, update, query through sequelize just works perfectly.

Today I was going to make the query ordered by `Task.end_time - Task.start_time`, sounds easy, doesn't it? However it proved to be very tricky if not impossible using sequelize.

As the options object passed into `findAll` method contains nested `include` arrays to retrieve the child tables, the SQL generated actually is complicated and containing subqueries.

I have tried `sequelize.literal`, `sequelize.fn`, none worked, and the reasons are the same - sequelize put the ORDER BY clause in two places - one in a subquery where the field names are still in underscored form, e.g. `start_time` and `end_time` and the other in the end of the sql, where the field names have been aliased to `startTime` and `endTime`, therefore the `order` I specified can never satisfy both at the same time.

I also think of `Sequelize.VIRTUAL` data type, found [this post](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7350) however the trick didn't work either. The SQL generated was wrong:

```
"Task"."endTime - startTime as runningTime" FROM "task"
```

Any advice / suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: How, exactly, are you coding literal()?  This works fine for me `Meeting.findAll({
            order : [[ Sequelize.literal(' t_meeting.updatedAt - t_meeting.createdAt'), 'DESC']]
        })`   (t_meeting being the table name, NOT the model name... and both fields being of type DATETIME )

Comment: @KenOn10 I copied the generated SQL in pgAdmin and 100% sure the error was because of field name conversion, as sequelize generates the SQL something like this (simplified version):

`select * from (select end_time as endTime, start_time as startTime from Task ORDER BY (end_time - start_time)) as Task left outer join (...) as Child ON ... WHERE ... ORDER BY (end_time - start_time)`

Obviously the (end_time - start_time) in the end of the SQL won't work.

Comment: Could be a problem in your model, the associations or the find() statement.  I suggest you post more code....